# Why is liquibase changeset not used with liquibase maven plugin update

Tags: liquibase

using liquibase inside a spring boot project in combination with the liquibase maven plugin.

I'v added the following changeset:

```
<changeSet author="mrx" id="1642181924202-55">
        <addColumn tableName="users" >
            <column name="email"
                    type="varchar(255)">
            </column>
        </addColumn>
    </changeSet>
```

The liquibase properties:

```
url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/mydb
username=root
classpath=mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar
password=test
ChangeLogFile=liquibaseChangeLog.xml
driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
outputChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibaseChangeLog.xml
diffExcludeObjects=table:ACT_.*
logLevel=finest
diffTypes=data,tables,views,columns,indexes,foreignkeys,primarykeys,uniqueconstraints
```

in application.yaml of spring boot:

```
liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:liquibaseChangeLog.xml
```

And then I'm running from intellij the maven liquibase plugin action "update" but the table is not altered and the changelog does not contain the -55 id so it is not used.

The changelog was generated before from an existing DB, this worked and when I delete the whole DB liquibase recreates it. Only cannt add one simple column here by hand.

How can I get this to work? Is my changeset missing some info? (I deleted parameters schema and catalog, seemed like I did not need them and I wouldnt know what to fill in, the id is just the same as the last generated one +1) That the changeset adds actually a simple column like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I ran all the time liquibase update and it did not work but after I simply build the project and started the spring boot app, the changelog was applied correctly. :/